# Edit tax calculation in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on an existing Magento 1.9 project.

Here is the scenario

In admin panel i have set the product price to 118, now in front end it showing the price to 100 + 18% tax, same in the checkout cart.

I just want to show 118 without any tax, how can i do that. Any guidance or pointing in direction will be a great help, this is my first php work..

Update to question
Now i have update all tax rate to 0, but it is still reducing the prices as mentioned above, so i look at the My SQL table Sales_flate_quote, and it shows the price in column name subtotal-->495.76, base_subtotal--> 585, the price i set in magento is 585. i am still finding the possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin > System > Configuration > VAT & other taxes > Price display settings > Dislay products price in catalog > HT, TTC, HT & TTC`

If you don't want a Tax at all, you have to remove it or you don't select it in : `price product tab > Vat class > No`

Comment: no, its not like that, looks like previous developer edited tax calculation in codes not in settings